# Ng Serve Won't Stop

Tags: angular, xampp, angular-cli

I'm trying to use XAMPP to run Apache but every time I start the service it dies. When I visit "localhost" on my browser I see the "It works!" text that is displayed when you serve a new Angular project but I don't have that process running in any terminal. I've tried resetting my machine but can't seem to terminate that process, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use the Apache to serve an Angular project you might want to use the python server, if you are on Linux/Mac.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

or there is a good node module by John Papa:

```
$ npm install -g lite-server
# cd into your project and run:
$ lite-server
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to stop Angular. I have a project that is not Angular based that I'm trying to view via Apache but "Ng Serve Won't Stop".  I don't even know where it's serving from.

Comment: @jadeallencook are you on mac or Linux?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS

Comment: if you know the port you can use this command to find the PID and then kille the process:  `sudo lsof -i :port`  and then `kill pidNumber`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156754/discussion-between-jadeallencook-and-jgatjens).

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Apache httpd daemon.

```
sudo apachectl stop
```